# Unable to load caliper results online

Tags: java, benchmarking, caliper

I followed few suggestions available online but none has helped.

Got caliper and built it from https://github.com/peterlynch/caliper

`export CLASSPATH=/home/deepakkv/projects/poc/benchmarkparquet/target/classes:~/.m2/repository/com/google/code/caliper/caliper/1.0-SNAPSHOT/caliper-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:~/projects/poc/caliper/lib/gson.jar:~/projects/poc/caliper/lib/allocation.jar:~/projects/poc/caliper/lib/guava-r09.jar`

Now to push the results to web, we need to specify the key. Here is the confusion. I included the API key in both ways

$ cat /home/deepakkv/.caliperrc

key

$ cat /home/deepakkv/.caliper/config.properties

results.upload.options.key = key

$

I ran the benchmark as follows

$ sh ~/projects/poc/caliper/scripts/caliper  com.parquet.benchmark.BenchmarkParquetDirectWrites
0% Scenario{vm=java, trial=0, benchmark=TestContains1, length=1} 6.47 ns; σ=0.32 ns @ 10 trials
50% Scenario{vm=java, trial=0, benchmark=TestContains2, length=1} 5.34 ns; σ=0.22 ns @ 10 trials
benchmark   ns linear runtime
TestContains1 6.47 ==============================
TestContains2 5.34 ========================
vm: java
trial: 0
length: 1
$

It ran successfully, did not indicate it was posting results to web. I could not find anything @ http://microbenchmarks.appspot.com/runs

Where am i going wrong ?

Comment: I'm not sure why you built caliper from that repository.  Can you use the latest version from https://code.google.com/p/caliper/ ?